# unable to display my images stored in the database

Tags: php, mysql

i want to display all the images stored in the database.. then my problem is that only small square will appear.. i need help..

my maincontent.php

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error());
   $sql = "SELECT id FROM products";
   $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<img src="t2.php?id='.$row['id'].'"/>';
    }
    mysql_close($link);
        ?>
```

my t2.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not&amp;nbsp;connect: " .  mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("login") or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT photo FROM products WHERE id={$_GET['id']}";

$result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo mysql_result($result, 0);
mysql_close($link);
}else{
echo 'Please use&;nbsp;a real id number';

}
?>
```

i hope someone can help me regarding this problem.

Comment: im using blob in saving the image in the database.
the output is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87636874/Capture.JPG

Comment: What do you get when you manually open `t2.php?id=SOMEID` in your browser? You should check that because you are using `echo` for your errors and you cannot see those inside `<img>` tag.

Comment: I can't spot an error. Are you sure the blob was saved correctly? Could you provide mysqldunp for a few lines?

Comment: yes. the image is saved in the database but it wont display in my homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you saved your image in your database(direct images or image path). but it seems that you have to be changed those:

Change this line :

```
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

to:

```
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

and your t2.php

Change :

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

to :

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
```

you need to use `mysqli_*` or  `PDO` . `mysql_*` all functions are deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Change to this.   your t2.php

```
 <?php
    $imageId = intval($_GET["id"]);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT img FROM images WHERE id = ". $imageId);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $mime = null;
    // place $type init. here
    if ($type=="pjpeg") // <<< where do you get $type btw?
        $mime = "image/jpeg";

    $b64Src = "data:".$mime.";base64," . base64_encode($row["img"]);
    echo '<img src="'.$b64Src.'" alt="" />';
    ?>
```

Comment: How is that going to help him display the image using `echo '<img src="t2.php?id='.$row['id'].'"/>';` ?